# How to programmatically configure an ODBC Datasource using C#

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

Is there any way to create a ODBC DSN with C#?

Maybe a P/invoke?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Registry classes to write the dsn info in the registry, under

```
HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources
```

You'll need to check what values are needed for you ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

Following resources might be helpful:

MSDN:

[How To Use the ODBC .NET Managed Provider in Visual C# .NET and Connection Strings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310988)

CodeProject.com

[An ODBC (DSN/Driver) Manager DLL written in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sdbODBCMngr.aspx)

You can try to invoke functions:

SQLWriteDSNToIni and ConfigDSN (MSDN links are dead for some reason, try to google by functions names)

Answer (score 1):

An example of the Registry Keys and Values required to create an ODBC Data Source for SQL Server can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170466/what-is-the-simplest-most-maintainable-way-to-create-a-sql-server-odbc-data-sou#170490).